# Loading progress before playing video in videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want a progress bar (not progress bar dailog )before the video plays(while it loads) in the videoview. Thinking of any other way of doing this without using onpreparedlistener().

Answer (score 0):

use this example to show prograssbar before playing vedio  http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-show-progressbar-while-loading-a-video-in-android-videoview/

Comment: Don't post link as a answer. It use as a reference. Link can be vanish if the reference page will be deleted !

Comment: But the example you told uses onpreparedlistener (). I want alternatives without using onpreparedlistener ().

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call this method when video start playing :

```
private void bufferingController(){

         bufferhandler = new Handler(); 
         bufferhandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    int duration = videoview.getCurrentPosition();
                    //System.out.println("duration "+duration);

                    //System.out.println("oldduration = "+old_duration +" duration = "+duration);
                    if (old_duration  == duration  ) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      }
                   else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                    old_duration  = duration;
                  }
            }, 1000);
            }
```